# why jTextArea.setText(); only show latest value?

Tags: java, client-server, jtextarea

So i was tried to show data from server to gui jTextArea.setText() for every receive data from server but it only show the latest value.

So this is code from class A:

```
while (true) {
                String receivedCommand = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (receivedCommand != null) {
                    this.commandFromServer = receivedCommand;
                    sendCommand(this.commandFromServer);
  
                    bufferedWriter.write("Accepted Command");
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.flush();

                    if (receivedCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnect")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

public void sendCommand(String command) {
        MainFrame.getCommandFromServer(command);
    }
```

and this is code from class B:

```
public static void getCommandFromServer(String command){
        System.out.println(command);
        chatReceiveText.setText(command);
  
    }
```

the print out is working as it show the response on console but for textArea.setText is not working as i am expected as it only show latest values after loop is break, how can textArea can set text based on server response?

Comment: `setText` sets, as the text, the string you give it. What did you think `setText` would do? You might like to look at `insert` and `append` Incidentally, you should be getting the response and setting that in the gui in separate threads ideally. You might find it fails if you don't

Comment: I just want to show response from server, so every time it got new response it will update and show in textArea. And thanks for advice.

Comment: I don't think you're being clear: **B**: *I just want to show response from server, so every time it got new response it will update and show in textArea* **A** *... but it only show the latest value.* Those two things are entirely consistent, so why are you stating you have a problem?

Comment: The problem are like this
Loop:
Server: command1
Server: command2
Break

The textArea only display command2 and skip command1, but console in this case print out can show all command. But I want to display command1 after that command2 in texArea.

Comment: @OleV.V. - terrible idea. That means you have to get the text from the Document and create a String of the text. Then you have to add the text to the Document which means it needs to replace the text in the Document and then parse the new text into the Document. Just use the `append(...)` method of the `JTextArea` as was originally suggested by @g00se.

Comment: @camickr I have to agree. :-) In addition I would probably want to consider a better separation of model and UI, but this may be out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @camickr, i tried use append but the result is different it just show the result after loop is break in my previous example woud command1command2 any idea how to show it every iteration inside loop?
so when iteration1 = command1, gui will show it and iteration2 = command2 and so on and must be show it

schema must be like this iteration -> shown gui -> iteration2 -> shown gui -> break but for your advice it work like this iteration 1 -> iteration 2 -> break -> shown gui.

Comment: You're now entering into the difficulties I described above. For this to work in an orderly way you need to organise your threading. I suggest the excellently-documented [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: owh i see, now i am know the problem thanks @g00se, gui programming has a lot to do haha...

Comment: Also see: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).